# Sum of some spacified columns of the NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array as following:

```
>>> a = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
      [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
      [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

I wonder how to sum the 1st and 4th columns of this array?
I'll appreciate it if someone can give me some help.

Comment: Do you mean `a[:, 0] + a[:, 3]`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by?

```
>>> a[:, [0, 3]].sum(0)
array([36, 48])
>>>
```

Or to sum together:

```
>>> a[:, [0, 3]].sum()
84
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> a[:, 0] + a[:, 3]
84
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the columns row-wise, use:

```
a[:, [0,3]].sum(1)
```

output:

```
array([ 3, 15, 27, 39])
```